# Is my understanding of "random" correct?

Tags: statistics, random

I am doing an research and trying to choose items for my questionaire ramdomly.But I feel that I am not very clear why I must use ramdomization .

I know that choosing items ramdomly is to prevent the case that there may be some factors contained in a nonrandom selection other than the conditions I set in my experiment would cause the final result ,so that I cann't draw the conclusion that the final result is derived only from the experimental conditions I set.

So I wonder if I can perceive the concept of ramdomization in my experiment in this way :  ("-->"means "cause",and "null" means not any particular factor)

(1) null-->selction of items
   (2)selection of items , experimetal conditions, some other factors-->final result

By (1)(2),we have:

null,expermental conditions ,some other factors-->final result

Therefore, the selection of the items doesn't account for my final experiment result which is what I intend to make .
Is my understanding of random selection in the form:

null-->selection

and how it may affect my experiment result right? I would aprreciate it very much if someone could give me some suggestions !

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is *I am doing an research and trying to choose items for my questionaire ramdomly*. So I assume you are conducting a survey. The aim of the survey will dictate what questions to ask (the data you are collecting). The randomisation enters picture only in deciding *whom to ask the questions, or from whom to collect the data* (it is not practical to ask everyone).

If your aim is to find out how much a family spends on eating pizzas every month, the question to ask is clear. How much they spend on pizzas and how much is their monthly income (to get an idea of proportion of income spent on this). So your wordings "choose items for my questionnaire randomly" is vague.

Randomisation is needed so that you don't end up collecting  the data only from college students or from factory workers, or from professional sports persons(they may be careful about eating out).

Comment: Thank you for you answer and I would like to make my question more specific.

Comment: What i am doing is an linguistic experiment where i need to expose the target sentences to the subjects and record their reading time.There are 26 groups of sentences and each group contains 4 sentences .Since sentences in the same group are similar and  may cause confusion to the subjects ,i need to confirm that a subject exposed with a sentence would not be exposed to any of the other 3 sentences in the same group.There are many permutations which satisfy this and what i need to make sure is that my selection of such permutations won't bias my experment result .

Comment: You should discuss with statisticians rather than mathematicians: especially those who study *Design of Experiments*. In general statisticians discuss how to process data, and and how to draw inferences and how to test hypotheses. This branch of statistics does not deal with data processing: rather with collection of data with care so that meaningful conclusion is possible.